# How to call method from div in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a div and I just want to render it on a condition, I also want to call the method if the condition comes true here is my code

```
 <div v-if="timetable === null" "mymethodhere">
      <h4>no data found</h4>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a watcher on timetable and if timetable === null do things.

```
  watch: {
    "timetable": function (newVal) {
       if (newVal === null) {
         ---> do things
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a watcher on `timetable`

```
watch: {
    timetable(timetable){
        if (timetable === null){
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
},
```

Official docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html